# CakePHP Tags Model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a simple app that has Posts and Tags.

A post can have multiple tags and tags can belong to multiple posts. The basic DB schema is like this:

post table:

```
id
title
slug
content
```

tag table:

```
id
title
slug
```

tag_posts table:

```
id
tag_id
post_id
```

So when a user saves a post it will take a list of tags in a field and then first check if the tags exist. If the tag doesn't exist, then create them, or if not get there existing ids. (all tags are lower-cased so you can't have `Tag` and `tag`). The tags are then linked to the post by adding the ids into the `tag_posts` table.

This works so far, but the code to do it is really horrible. I have the following method in the Tag model which takes the list of tags and does the above:

public function savePostTags($postId, $tags)
{

```
// Explode the topics by comma, so we have an array to run through
$tags = explode(',', $tags);
// Array for collecting all the data
$collection = array();

//debug($tags);

function is_array_empty( $mixed ) {
    if ( is_array($mixed) ) {
        foreach ($mixed as $value) {
            if ( ! is_array_empty($value) ) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    } elseif ( ! empty($mixed) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

if(is_array_empty($tags) ) {

    return false;

}

// First of all we bin off existing associations to make sure we don't duplicate
// NOTE: The false means don't delete the topics or posts related!!! VERY IMPORTANT!
$this->TagPost->deleteAll(array('TagPost.post_id' => $postId), false);

$tags = array_unique($tags);

// Make sure all tags are unique

foreach($tags as $tag)
{
    // Trim it so remove unwanted white spaces in the beginning and the end.
    $tag = trim($tag);

    // If tag is empty exit here
    if(empty($tag) ) {

        return false;

    }

    // Make it all lowercase for consistency of tag names
    $tag = strtolower($tag);

    // Check if we already have a topic like this
    $controlFind = $this->find(
        'first',
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'title' => $tag
            )
        )
    );

    //debug($controlFind);

    // No record found (create new tag and link it up)
    if(!$controlFind)
    {
        $this->create();
        if(
            !$this->save(
                array(
                    'title' => $tag,
                    'slug' => Inflector::slug($tag)
                )
            )
        )
        {
            // If only one saving fails we stop the whole loop and method.
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $temp = array(
                'TagPost' => array(
                    'tag_id' => $this->id,
                    'post_id' => $postId
                )
            );
        }
    }
    else // Or if found link it with the post
    {
        $temp = array(
            'TagPost' => array(
                'tag_id' => $controlFind['Tag']['id'],
                'post_id' => $postId
            )
        );
    }

    $collection[] = $temp;
}

return $this->TagPost->saveAll($collection, array('validate' => false));
```

}

Any ideas on how to refactor this?

As it feels really long-winded and seems to break the conventions of CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public function savePostTags($postId, $tags)
        {
            $tags = explode(',', $tags);
            foreach($tags as $key=>$value){
              $listTags[$key] = trim(strtolower($value));    
            }
            # find the list of existing tags
            $listOfExistingTags = $this->find('list',
                         array('conditions' => array('title' => $tags),
                         'recursive' => -1));
            $newTags = array_diff($tags, $listOfExistingTags);
            #save new tags
            foreach($newTags as $key=>$value){
                 $saveData[$key]['Tag']['title'] =  $value;
                 $saveData[$key]['Tag']['slug']  =  Inflector::slug($value);
             }
            if(!empty($saveData))$this->saveAll($saveData);
            # this save all the tags
            # now save data in tag_posts
            $listOfExistingTags = $this->find('list',
               array('conditions' =>array('title' => $tags),
                     'fields'=>array('id','title'),
                     'recursive' => -1));  
            $i = 0;
            foreach($listOfExistingTags as $key=>$value){
                $tagPostData[$i]['TagPost']['tag_id']  = $key;  
                $tagPostData[$i]['TagPost']['post_id'] = $postId; $i++; 
            }
            if(!empty($tagPostData)){
            App::import('model','TagPost');
            $TagPost = new TagPost();
            $TagPost->saveAll($tagPostData);
           }
        }
```

Comment: Cool I'll give that a try when I get home. Do you have any ideas why the code I posted was duplicating the tags in 2.4.4? Curious more than anything. Thanks.

Comment: But what was causing the duplication then? It didn't use to duplicate in older versions of Cake.

Comment: the actual reason of duplicate can be answered if you provide some more data

Comment: Just tried your code and it duplicates the tags and every new save (editing a post). Turns out the problem with mine was that I was deleting based on the wrong ID. But noticed that you don't clear the tags first before adding them...

Comment: Also if I do: test, test, test it will save them all as it doesn't check if any duplicates on the initial save.

Comment: Also noticed yours saves spaces in the tags. So I get ` tag`

Comment: I've updated my code in my original post so that it now works and fixes all of the aforementioned issues... but the code is awful :/

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas on how to refactor this?

Use [the CakeDC Tags plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/tags). It is unit tested and easy to throw in, takes ~15mins. See it's readme.md. Its basically just adding the behavior and adding a field "tags" to your form.